# Would it be possible to overload modulus to; when receiving only a leading number; return the number/100 in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm curious if there are possibilities outside of a simple function or construct. Though a slight simplification of my code it would add up to a lot to not have to write in the conversion of a percentage back and forth between displaying and calculating.

Comment: You mean making it unary? No that is not possible.

Comment: Define a type that represents percentages.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create a brand new postfix operator out of thin air. The list, syntax, and precedence of the operators is set into stone.

However, there is something in the language that just might be close enough for your needs: [User-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

```
constexpr long double operator ""_pct(unsigned long long int v) {
  return (long double)v / 100;
}

void foo() {
  double x = 30_pct;
}
```

That can only be used on literal values, as opposed to arbitrary expressions. But again, that's as good as you're going to get.

Comment: Good point we use this a lot for constants with a unit like distances, (_km, _m, _cm and _mm). It does however only work with constants at compile time.

Comment: Footnote: For the sake of completeness, you could also get almost the equivalent at runtime by using tag-dispatching with an overloaded binary operator like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hEb6andGb). But that's just messing with the syntax at that point, and is probably more hurtful than anything in the long run.

Comment: O yes that is border line ;-) You really need to be careful and place brackets around that to get the right order of operation if you where to use it in an mathematical operation.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to define a type which will handle percentage.

```cpp
class Percentage {
public:
    constexpr Percentage(int); // use explicit? This depends on requirements
    constexpr Percentage(unsigned long long int);
    constexpr Percentage(double); 

    constexpr operator int() const;
    constexpr operator double() const;

    constexpr Precentage fromRatio(double x) {
        return {x * 100};
    }
private:
    .....
};

// custom literal is just sugar coating
Percentage operator ""_pct(unsigned long long int v) {
  return Percentage(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) already discussed, you could use a percentage value type. Something like:

```
class Percent
{
public:
    constexpr Percent(double v) : val(v) {} 

    constexpr double value() const { return val; }
    constexpr double scale() const { return val / 100; }

    /** \brief Multiply a number by its scaled value
     *  Can also be done as a free function
     */
    double operator *(double other) const 
    {
        return other * scale();
    }

    // other operators

private:
    double val;
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Percent p)
{
    os << p.value() << '%';
    return os;
}
```

Using `constexpr` correctly, you should be able to get the result you want without any runtime overhead.